# Making a drop down list using swift3

Tags: swift, xcode, drop-down-menu, uibutton, dropdown

[I am new to Xcode and the Swift3 language, so can anyone please direct me on how to implement the drop down list in swift3?When I click uibutton open dropdown list.i use three type of button first one is "country" second "city" and third "locality".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxknI.png)

Comment: use google, there is multiple libraries for that and examples

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to implement a dropdown list in iOS is to use a UITableView. In your example you could create one programmatically and add it to the right place on the screen.

Or have one hidden and bring it from / make it visible when tapping the button.

One think about that though, it is not the best UX/UI to have drop down menus in an iOS app. Apple provides a lot of native elements that would do a similar job.

Example 1: Use a modal that has a UITableView (fullscreen or part of the screen) and make it disappear on selection.

Example 2: Use a UIPickerView

In case you still want to stay with that design use something like 
https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

I bet if you do a quick googling you'll find more libraries that do something similar

Comment: picker allows large list if not much iPhone screen space.